# SelectionFilterのフィルタ条件文字

Tags: vb.net, ijcad

SelectionFilterにてマルチ引出線(MLEADER)を選択したいのですが、下記のコードでは文字列は選択できますがマルチ引出線が選択できません。
マルチ引出線のフィルタ条件文字はMLEADERではないのでしょうか？

```
' データの選択条件(マルチ引出線 or 文字列)
    Dim typValArray(3) As TypedValue
    typValArray.SetValue(New TypedValue(DxfCode.Operator, "<OR"), 0)
    typValArray.SetValue(New TypedValue(DxfCode.Start, "MLEADER"), 1)
    typValArray.SetValue(New TypedValue(DxfCode.Start, "TEXT"), 2)
    typValArray.SetValue(New TypedValue(DxfCode.Operator, "OR>"), 3)

    ' 図形の選択フィルタ
    Dim selFilter As SelectionFilter = New SelectionFilter(typValArray)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

マルチ引出線のオブジェクトタイプの文字列は"MULTILEADER"です。

オブジェクトタイプの文字列がいまいちわからない時は、

```
RXObject.GetClass(GetType(MLeader)).DxfName
```

こんな感じでDxfNameプロパティを使用すると良いと思います。